# how to process logical operation between 2 BSONObj precreated in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I'm new to mongodb. I want to execute a query (a=3 OR b=5 as condition) using c++ driver..

I can create separately two BSONObj objects for each a=3 and b=5 through BSONObjBuilder as follows.

```
 mongo::BSONObjBuilder builder = new mongo::BSONObjBuilder;
 mongo::BSONObjBuilder inner = new BSONObjBuilder(builder->subobjStart(condition));
 inner->append("$gte", value);
 inner->append("$lte", value);

 mongo::BSONObj obj = builder.obj();
```

So i have 2 different BSONObj. And i can run them successfully. But how can i combine these objects using $or or $and logical operators.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your goal is the query `{$or: [{a: 3}, {a: 5}]}`, you could construct that with the MongoDB C++ driver as follows:

```
mongo::BSONObjBuilder queryBuilder;
mongo::BSONArrayBuilder orClause(queryBuilder.subarrayStart("$or"));
mongo::BSONObjBuilder firstClause(orClause.subobjStart()).append("a", 3).done();
mongo::BSONObjBuilder secondClause(orClause.subobjStart()).append("a", 5).done();
orClause.done();
mongo::BSONObj query(queryBuilder.obj());
```

And here's a much less verbose way using the OR helper:

```
mongo::BSONObj query(OR(BSON("a" << 3), BSON("a" << 5));
```